# vb.net add basket logic

Tags: .net

hi guys am new to vb.net, i am working on application that needs Shopping Basket,
can anyone help me how to add product details in basket and is will carry to the new page ?is it with the help of session ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Session is an easy way to manage a shopping cart during a users browsing of the store.